# Problem in finding x intercepts of this function: $f(x) = 3\ln|x−1|−1/2x^2−x$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

$f(x) = 3\ln|x−1|−1/2x^2−x$

I tried to get this function on a graph calculator and beside revealing the intersection point $(0, 0)$, it also showed and interesting point that approximates to $x = 4.123$, yet doing this algebraically I can see why it yields $(0, 0)$ but I'm having trouble to figure out the other $x$ intercept to that second point or even why should I bother with it in the first place, I'm sure that analyzing the growth gives a clear picture of what's going on with the function. I tried to treat it with the quadratic formula but I'm sure I'm off the rails with the result, if I can gain any insight with how develop the solutions to $3\ln|x−1|−1/2x^2 − x = 0$  it would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you expect such a complicated function to have roots that can be determined with a closed formula ? This is rather unlikely , I doubt that Lambert-W will help. The root $0$ can be "guessed" , the other root(s) must be determined numerically. It will also be not easy to show that there are no more roots.

Comment: I don't have the analytical tools to take a clear cut on the functions yet, so I'm trying my best with what I can